# state and payload is undefined when reducer is bounded in app.module.ts

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, ngrx

I was trying to use ngrx, but when I bind the reducer into my app.module.ts file, I get undefined payload, and the state is also undefined, is there something I got wrong in here? sorry, this is my first time integrating redux in angular, I've done it in react, but it's a bit different in Angular.

this is my **module.ts** file

```
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store'
import { rootReducer } from './reducer'

@NgModule({
  StoreModule.forRoot({
    message: rootReducer
  })
})
```

this is my **reducer.ts** file

```
import { Model } from './models/app.model'
import * as list from './actions/action.actions'

const initialState: Model = {
  message: '',
  value: 0
}

export function rootReducer(state: Model[] = [initialState], action: list.Actions) {
  console.log(state, action.payload)
  switch(action.type) {
    case list.SPANISH:
      return [ ...state, action.payload ]
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

This is my **actions.ts** file

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store'
import { Model } from './../models/app.model'

export const SPANISH = "[Choose Language] Spanish"

export class ChangeValue implements Action {
    type  = SPANISH

    constructor (public payload: Model[]) { }
}

export type Actions = ChangeValue
```

My **model.ts** file

```
export interface Model {
    message: string;
    value: number;
}
```

The error says that **property payload is missing in type 'Action' but required in type 'ChangeValue'**

Comment: Please post your code as text rather than images.

Comment: hi @Connell.O'Donnell, I edited the code, BTW the error is in app.module.ts file, seems like I can't bind a key to my reducer